# SQLPlus Query SELECT on a table containing asterisks

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

When executing this code in SQL Plus:

```
set heading off
set colsep ';'
set feedback off
column descripcion format a50
set linesize 250
SPOOL lineas.txt
SELECT codigo, n_pedido, precio, calid1, calid2, fecha, cantidad, descripcion
FROM TABLA_PED
WHERE
SERIE = 'WEB'
AND venta = 25;
SPOOL OFF;
QUIT;
```

Works perfect but if there are asterisks in the "descripcion" it returns unexpected results.

Is there a way to avoid this?
Completely new in this, any help appreciated.

Comment: Welcome, it would be nice to explain what you mean by "_ it returns unexpected results._".

Comment: Are you talking about something unexpected in the SQL\*Plus session? In the text file? When you process the file or screen output somehow? (e.g. your shell interpreting the `*` and showing file names from your current directory.) Include the raw data in the table, what you expect to see, and what is actually happening - we can't guess.

Comment: Thank you. The SQL*Plus session finish ok but in the output text file the lines that contain asterisks generate empty fields, someting like this: codigo;n_pedido;precio;calid1;calid2;fecha;cantidad; descricio;;;;;;;;n

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried cast it as nVarchar? Like:

```
set heading off
set colsep ';'
set feedback off
column descripcion format a50
set linesize 250
SPOOL lineas.txt
SELECT codigo, n_pedido, precio, calid1, calid2, fecha, cantidad, CAST (descripcion as nvarchar2(240)) as "descripcion"
FROM TABLA_PED
WHERE
SERIE = 'WEB'
AND venta = 25;
SPOOL OFF;
QUIT;
```

Comment: You would need to provide a size for the cast; but why would this make any difference anyway?

Comment: Just a try, maybe there is a bug with asterisk signs it interprets as a command. You could provide at least the output of the column if there are sensible informations in your query.

Comment: Tried with the CAST as nvarchar with similar results.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers. It seems that the length "a50" was not enough for the descripcion field so the output did this empty fields thing.
Just changed to "a250" and fixed.